# django-admin.py on win7 asked programm for open

Tags: django, windows-7, django-admin

I have installed Django on Win7 and try

```
 >>> import django
 >>> django.VERSION
(1, 2, 3, 'final', 0)
```

it works. But when I call django-admin.py startproject myappname, Windows show me dialog with ask what program it should use to open this command. If I check python.exe then django-admin.py always show me help about django-admin.py

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Windows show me dialog with ask what program it should use to open this command.

You can avoid this by using Python explicitly, provided Python.exe is in your `PATH`. For e.g.
`python /path/to/django-admin.py startproject myappname`.

> If I check python.exe then django-admin.py always show me help about django-admin.py

From the [documentation](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/django-admin/?from=olddocs#startproject-projectname) for `django-admin.py startproject`:

> This command is disabled when the `--settings` option to `django-admin.py` is used, or when the environment variable `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` has been set. To re-enable it in these situations, either omit the `--settings` option or unset `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE`.

Can you check if you have set an environment variable named `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE`? If yes, remove/unset it and try again.

Comment: Problem resolved thank you, but python was already in PATH directory.

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same problen that raise this error when I ran django-admin.py on Command prompt I couldn't create a projects.
I tried to Run Regedit by using Find to Search python.exe and then adding %% but it was not sufficient... I then added the necessary Path to the System PATH as Shown Below.
(Control Panel -> System -> Advanced ->Environment Variables -> PATH). Add to the PATH
C:\Python27\python.exe;C:\Python27\Scripts;C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\django\bin
Adam It Work!!! Now I can Create Django Projects and applications Using Command on Windows 7